# How can an absolute beginner begin with cyber security?

Tags: python, professional-education

I am an absolute beginner in coding/computer science and want to pursue a particular role in cyber security open to all degrees (I am studying chemical engineering). Can anyone recommend what I should start with/Where I should learn it? I have time and I want to impress interviewers.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you want to focus on? Do you have particular interests within cyber security? Do you have experience with computers or programming?

Comment: Information security is a vast, vast topic. You need to have an idea of what you want to learn (pentesting, binary exploitation, incident report, malware analysis, etc.). Otherwise, it would probably be a good idea to start learning more about computers in general. Try different operating systems like Linux, BSD, or Solaris and get used to them. Learn how to create a website from scratch by buying a VPS and configuring the web server and database yourself. Learn how to program and how to read code. This may help.

Comment: @Sjoerd I'm not really sure as I have little experience with it. I have no experience with computers or programming, but I want to learn about this pretty quickly and can devote a lot of time to it. I have a technical background too (Physics, Maths at A-Level)

Comment: @forest Thanks, Is there any language you would suggest for me to learn first? or any places to learn them? I have heard about Python/javascript as being good. Also do you know of anywhere I can learn about the different topics in cyber security so I can narrow down my interest?

Comment: I'd start with Python, maybe even C. I started with C, fwiw.

Comment: @yusyus Infosec is *not* something you can learn *pretty quickly* but yeah forest gave a really good starting point you can follow

Comment: Along with Forest's, I started reading books in the stuff that I thought I was interesting. The authors generally point out prerequisites that you need before starting the book. Grab some more references for the prerequisites and slog your way through it. I've tried stuff, left it for something else, came back to it, and left it again. Eventually if you are chasing rabbits down their holes with curiosity things will start to come together. It's all a big web, everything you learn contributes to everything else, programming especially. But you don't have to be a pro programmer.